# Can RabbitMQ (or spring cloud stream) consume messages exclusively?

Tags: java, rabbitmq, amqp, spring-cloud-stream

I have a rabbitmq queue and two spring cloud spring consumers.
I want that each consumers process messages in order.

I thought that when consumer1 send ack, consumer2 receive second message,
so I expected message1, message2 is processed in order in each consumers.

```
-------------------- time pass ------------------------>

consumer1:   message1             message3
consumer2:              message2            message4
```

But it wasn't. consumer1, consumer2 receive message1, message2, and process simultaneously.

```
-------------------- time pass ------------------------>

consumer1:   message1  message3
consumer2:   message2  message4
```

Is there a way for spring cloud stream to consume messages exclusively?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

RabbitMQ (AMQP) doesn't support that; each consumer gets `prefetch` messages.

It does support exclusive consumers, but it means consumer1 would get all the messages and consumer2 would only get messages if consumer1 dies.

However, Spring Cloud Stream doesn't currently provide a property to set that option.

Comment: The GH issue on the matter: https://github.com/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-stream-binder-rabbit/issues/80

Comment: hi! I was just wondering if this feature has been implemented now ?

Comment: I meant can we do this with a load balanced option? Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

you would have to model your queues in a different way. E.g. by having an "incoming" queue which has exactly one consumer-coordinator. This consumer would relay messages to the "work" queue where consumer1+2 are both waiting and pick up work in a round robin way.

They would then signal completion to the coordinator on a third queue which would cause it to resume relaying a single message to the work queue.